# How can i resolve this error while trying to fetch data from wbgapi?

Tags: python

```
legal_enforcement = wb.data.DataFrame('ENF.CONT.COEN.ENFE.PR',
                                      countries,
                                     time = 2017)
legal_enforcement
```

`countries` is the array of all the countries' names.
I'm trying to get an indicator from the doing business database from world bank API wbgapi, but I keep getting an error saying:

> APIError: JSON decoding error
> (https://api.worldbank.org/v2/en/sources/2/series/ENF.CONT.COEN.ENFE.PR/country/ABW;AFE;AFG;AFW;AGO;ALB;AND;ARB;ARE;ARG;ARM;ASM;ATG;AUS;AUT;AZE;BDI;BEL;BEN;BFA;BGD;BGR;BHR;BHS;BIH;BLR;......;ZMB;ZWE/time/YR2017?per_page=1000&page=1&format=json)

I was expecting it to return a database with two columns, one stating the name of the countries and the other showing the values from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation https://pypi.org/project/wbgapi/. You are requesting from a database which currently is not the default. the default database looks from WDI database. So you have to first specify wb.db = 1.  then you can run your code. the code wb.db=1 instructs the API to look into the first database which is wb.db = 1 = "Doing business".

```
import wbgapi as wb
countries = ['KEN', 'ETH']

legal_enforcement = wb.data.DataFrame('ENF.CONT.COEN.ENFE.PR',
                                  countries,
                                 time = 2017, db=1)
legal_enforcement
```

Alternatively

```
wb.db = 1
legal_enforcement = wb.data.DataFrame('ENF.CONT.COEN.ENFE.PR',
                                  countries,
                                 time = 2017)
legal_enforcement
```

Output

| economy | ENF.CONT.COEN.ENFE.PR |
| --- | --- |
| ETH | 0.4 |
| KEN | 2.7 |